# How to get client IP address using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ip-address

I want to know how to get client IP address using jQuery?

Is it possible? I know pure javascript can't, but got some code using `JSONP` from Stack Overflow itself.

So, is there any workaround using jQuery?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

jQuery can handle JSONP, just pass an url formatted with the callback=? parameter to the `$.getJSON` method, for example:

```js
$.getJSON("https://api.ipify.org/?format=json", function(e) {
    console.log(e.ip);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This example is of a really simple JSONP service implemented on with `api.ipify.org`.

If you aren't looking for a cross-domain solution the script can be simplified even more, since you don't need the callback parameter, and you return pure JSON.

Comment: `jsonip.appspot.com` also apparently supports `CORS` as well as `JSONP`.

Comment: the server is down now, that is a good idea but I don't think it is reliable.

Comment: this server is down now. so we can simply remove appspot from jsonip.appspot.com.so it look like http://jsonip.com?callback=? thats all :)

Comment: @CMS you should answer the request limit of your provided api.

Answer (score 28):

A simple AJAX call to your server, and then the serverside logic to get the ip address should do the trick.

```
$.getJSON('getip.php', function(data){
  alert('Your ip is: ' +  data.ip);
});
```

Then in php you might do:

```
<?php
/* getip.php */
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
{
  $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
}
elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
{
  $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}
else
{
  $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
print json_encode(array('ip' => $ip));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
function GetUserIP(){
  var ret_ip;
  $.ajaxSetup({async: false});
  $.get('http://jsonip.com/', function(r){ 
    ret_ip = r.ip; 
  });
  return ret_ip;
}
```

If you want to use the IP and assign it to a variable, Try this. Just call `GetUserIP()`

Answer (score 1):

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Jquery - get ip address</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<h1>Your Ip Address : <span class="ip"></span></h1>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $.getJSON("http://jsonip.com?callback=?", function (data) {
        $(".ip").text(data.ip);
    });
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please provide some context to your answer. Such as, why does it work? Are there any disadvantages? Thanks!