# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number JSON ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jquery, jsonp

I'm trying to do a get request to a website and get the response.

I'm able to do a successful HTTP request and response, but for some reason the javascript error pops up and it breaks my code.

I'm assuming it is because of the new query parameter it is appending, like 
http://checkip.amazonaws.com/?callback=jQuery152011860558553598821_1374187260201&**_=1374187260214**

Code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/R7EPt/191/

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    var url = 'http://checkip.amazonaws.com/';
    $.getJSON(url + "?callback=?", null, function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
 });
```

Could some one help me!

Comment: No, that's just a parameter added by jQuery to prevent the browser caching the request you just done

Comment: So what do you think the error would be? It points to this link and says Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number. You could give it a try http://jsfiddle.net/R7EPt/191/

Comment: I think the problem is the retrieved content itself, it is not valid JSON, you should do the request with a simple `$.get`, see [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Comment: But with simple get it throws be a Cross Origin error.

Comment: I don't know how to solve this, but I have a sidenote for you: it's `$(document)`, not `$('document')`, since `document` is an object and not an HTML tag

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to issue a JSONP request from the client, but the server does not return a JSONP response. A JSONP response for the request `checkip.amazonaws.com/?callback=foo` would look like this:

```
foo("192.168.0.1");
```

Instead of just this:

```
192.168.0.1
```

### Edit

A solution to receive the user's IP via JSONP:
[Get user ip with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160157/get-user-ip-with-jquery)

Comment: I understood the problem. So is there a way to get this working in my scenario.

Comment: Yes, change the server side response. If you are not the server owner then there's nothing you can do.

Comment: By the way, you can get the user's IP in different ways.

Comment: Could you suggest me any CORS enabled sites using which I can get IP?