# Finding Approximate Physical Location of Client

Tags: javascript, jquery, geocoding

Is there a way to find where a client is located physically with Jquery? I have found how to get their [IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641868/how-to-get-client-ip-address-using-jquery), and also how to geocode their location with [geoplugin](http://www.geoplugin.com/), but I am wondering if there are other ways to do this? I don't need an exact location. Just approximate enough to know what state they are in to estimate a tax rate before they enter their actual state. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using IP address for geolocation (as per what you are already doing) is by far the most traditional way of doing it -- there are a new [W3C standard](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html) -- however it will promp people for permission (see demo [here](http://html5demos.com/geo)), as well as it for devices without embedded GPS (e.g. iPhone/Android) will have to draw on server side services for wifi and/or ip geolocation -- the fact that it will propt users means that it is probably not suitable for what you want to do.

Bigger website will use a tracking cookie to allow the site to lookup data the user have provided at previous visits -- so if you already have the shipping address from a customer from a previous visit, you can use the zip code which he provided earlier for you sales-tax estimation.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.maxmind.com/app/javascript_city

Include the JS file http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js & get location based on IP.

(Its not completely free, see website.)