# Get client IP address via third party web service

Tags: javascript, ip

I would like to read my ip address from the following page(http://l2.io/ip or other) using javascript to save him in my variable "myIp".

```
function getMyIP() {
  var myIp;
  ...
  return myIp;
}
```

How can you do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Client IP using just Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/get-client-ip-using-just-javascript)

Comment: The other question asks for a client-side JS solution. In contrast, this question asks about retrieving the IP address via some remote web service.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Checking your [linked site](http://l2.io/), you may include a script tag passing a `?var=desiredVarName` parameter which will be set as a global variable containing the IP address:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://l2.io/ip.js?var=myip"></script>
                                                      <!-- ^^^^ -->
<script>alert(myip);</script>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9ZrLz/)

I believe I don't have to say that this can be easily spoofed (through either use of proxies or spoofed request headers), but it is worth noting in any case.

---

### HTTPS support

In case your page is served using the `https` protocol, most browsers will block content in the same page served using the `http` protocol (that includes scripts and images), so the options are rather limited. If you have < 5k hits/day, the [Smart IP API](https://smart-ip.net/geoip-api) can be used. For instance:

```
<script>
var myip;
function ip_callback(o) {
    myip = o.host;
}
</script>
<script src="https://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=ip_callback"></script>
<script>alert(myip);</script>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/CKNMc/)

Edit: Apparently, this `https` service's certificate has expired so the user would have to add an exception manually. Open its API directly to check the certificate state: https://smart-ip.net/geoip-json

---

### With back-end logic

The most resilient and simple way, in case you have back-end server logic, would be to simply output the requester's IP inside a `<script>` tag, this way you don't need to rely on external resources. For example:

PHP:

```
<script>var myip = '<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>';</script>
```

There's also a more sturdy PHP solution (accounting for headers that are sometimes set by proxies) in this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1641894/1331430).

C#:

```
<script>var myip = '<%= Request.UserHostAddress %>';</script>
```

Comment: I tried it locally with Aptana studio and it works. But when I load it on my web page says "undefined"

Comment: Weird, have you included both script tags one after another? This should work as long as the site you're pinging is up.

Comment: The best approach, in case you have server-side logic, would be echoing the IP the user used to request the page. E.g. for PHP: `<script>var myip = '<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>';</script>`

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://l2.io/ip.js?var=myip"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/myscript.js" charset="UTF-8"></script> and in myscript I try to use myip

Comment: ^ I believe your first script's `src` has `http://` which Stack Overflow stripped 'cause you didn't format as code, well it should work fine. Maybe do a Ctrl+F5 after uploading the edited files to ensure that it is not a caching issue. `=]`

Comment: If you're using Chrome, check if the request is being made in Dev Tools (F12)'s Network tab: http://i.imgur.com/2oC7qal.png if the request doesn't appear there, check the page source to see if the script is actually there.

Comment: And finally make sure that you don't have `var myip;` inside of your script. And that you don't have `"use strict";` in the global scope (haven't tested but it might break due to the way the l2.io sets the global var)

Comment: Yes I use Chrome, in Dev Tools I read : blocked The page https://mypage... ran an insecure content from http://l2.io/ip.js?var=myip

Comment: Is your site running under `https`? I guess that's the issue. You won't be able to load data from `http` if so.

Comment: mmm...I need to have it in https. Is there a way to get the ip?

Comment: If you have a back-end server language, using that to get the user IP will be much simpler, secure and faster than relying on external resources. Else, if you have a static page, you'll need to use another site that offers an https version. I'll look for one meanwhile.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Before I used a get request to http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php and it worked but now the service is down.

Comment: I've found another service but it is over quota apparently https://jsonip.appspot.com/?callback=getip

Comment: I tried it yesterday and it worked but I did not try if it goes in https.

Comment: I think smart-ip.net functions but stops me jquery       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script> and with https doesn't work

Comment: That looks a bit weird, don't forget to use the `https` version of the jQuery CDN as well. `;)`

Comment: It works! I tried as you wrote ... instead of using jQuery and it works well with smart-ip.net. Thank a lot!

Comment: Why need to rely on 3rd party server? This wont work if the internet connection is not available!

Comment: @RafiqueMohammed well, that's because browsers do not provide any API to get the machine IP via vanilla JavaScript yet. Also, note that a given machine may be connected to multiple networks at the same time and thus have multiple IPs (up to one IP per network interface).

Answer (score 14):

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '//freegeoip.net/json/',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(location) {
            alert(location.ip);
        }
    });
```

This will work https too

Comment: the service is no longer available

Answer (score 9):

A more reliable REST endpoint would be http://freegeoip.net/json/

Returns the ip address along with the geo-location too. Also has cross-domain requests enabled (Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *) so you don't have to code around JSONP.

Comment: the service is no longer available

Answer (score 4):

If you face an issue of CORS, you can use https://api.ipify.org/.

```
function httpGet(theUrl)
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false );
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}


publicIp = httpGet("https://api.ipify.org/");
alert("Public IP: " + publicIp);
```

I agree that using synchronous HTTP call is not good idea. You can use async ajax call then.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <script type="application/javascript">
            function getip(json){
            alert(json.ip); // alerts the ip address
    }
    </script>

    <script type="application/javascript" src="http://jsonip.appspot.com/?callback=getip"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This pulls back client info as well.

```
var get = function(u){
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest;
    x.open('GET', u, false);
    x.send();
    return x.responseText;
}

JSON.parse(get('http://ifconfig.me/all.json'))
```

Comment: This does not work because cross-origin requests are not allowed. Also, doing synchronous requests is unspeakably evil.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if in the HTML you import a script...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//stier.linuxfaq.org/ip.php"></script>
```

You can then use the variable userIP (which would be the visitor's IP address) anywhere on the page.

To redirect: `<script>if (userIP == "555.555.555.55") {window.location.replace("http://192.168.1.3/flex-start/examples/navbar-fixed-top/");}</script>`

Or to show it on the page: `document.write (userIP);`

DISCLAIMER: I am the author of the script I said to import. The script comes up with the IP by using PHP. The source code of the script is below.

`<?php 
 //Gets the IP address
 $ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR") ; 
 Echo "var userIP = '" . $ip . "';"; 
 ?>`