# Change inline script to function

Tags: javascript, return-value, ip-address

Still pretty new to Javascript, so sorry if this is overly basic.

I have found this script that, when run inline, returns your IP.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://l2.io/ip.js"></script>
```

http://l2.io/ip.js Has nothing more than a line of code that says

```
document.write('123.123.123.123');
```

(But obviously with the user's IP address)

I want to use this IP address as a return string for a function defined externally (but still on my domain).

I.e.

```
function getIP() {
    return (THAT SCRIPT'S OUTPUT);
}
```

Herein lies the issue; I can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: That file http://l2.io/ip.js isn't pure javascript, but the code it displayed is rendered by some server side code. You could retrieve the content of that file and extract the ip from it

Comment: Why not put your "getIP()" function which returns the IP into the external script file and then call it from your code

Comment: There seems to be [an exact dup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17414972/get-ip-address-with-javascript) with a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a hack but you could do something like this

```
<body>
  <div id="externalip">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://l2.io/ip.js"></script>
  </div>
  <script>
    var ip = $('#externalip').text();

    alert(ip);
  </script>
</body>
```