# Use external inline script as local function

Tags: javascript, return-value, ip-address

Had this closed once as a duplicate, yet the so-called duplicate DID NOT actually address my whole question.

I have found this script that, when run inline, returns your IP.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://l2.io/ip.js"></script>
```

http://l2.io/ip.js Has nothing more than a line of code that says

```
document.write('123.123.123.123');
```

(But obviously with the user's IP address)

I want to use this IP address as a return string for a function DEFINED EXTERNALLY, BUT STILL ON MY DOMAIN. That is, I have a "scripts.js" that contains all the scripts I wish to use, and I would like to include it in that list as a local function that calls to the 12.io function, but javascript won't allow the <> tags, so I am unsure as to how to do this.

I.e.

```
function getIP() {
    return (THAT SCRIPT'S OUTPUT);
}
```

This is the topic this was supposedly a duplicate of, and it is very similar.

[Get client IP address via third party web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17414972/get-ip-address-with-javascript)

However, this DOES NOT address defining as a forwarded script it in my own script file.

Comment: Hm, I'm tempted to close this as a duplicate again - the answer basically is **read [the docs](http://l2.io/) of the site you are using**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you seem to want your site's users' IP to be used, you'll need to have client-side code to have their browsers make the request to `http://l2.io/ip`.

You will need AJAX. Using [jQuery's AJAX API](http://api.jQuery.com/jquery.get):

```js
$.get("http://l2.io/ip.js")
    .done(function(ip) {
        // do whatever you like with the ip...
    })
    .fail(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

According to Bergi (and with reason), the data should never leave the callback to avoid synchronism problems. It's advisable to use [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Comment: Simply don't load `http://l2.io/ip.js` but [`http://l2.io/ip`](http://l2.io/ip) - there's no need to extract the IP address.

Comment: I don't know the site; I'm using what the OP gave me! Thanks, anyway.

Comment: It's basically described in the duplicated he linked :-)

Comment: Gah, that was edited after I answered, or while I was.

Comment: Ok, only the relevant part's left.

Comment: Btw, try not to make `ip` a global variable. [ajax is asynchronous](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1048572), and this assignment might lead the OP on the wrong path.

Comment: No point setting ip as a private variable to the anonymous function. Unless you mean declaring it inside the `done` function as `window.ip`...

Comment: Irregardless of whether that variable is global or module-scoped, the rule of thumb is that the value should never ever leave a callback. You might want to return a promise.