# How my ip address will come automatically in a texbox

Tags: html

I have a textbox in a page call enquiry.

i want when my page loads my ip address will come automatically in that texbox... please help me..i need your suggestions as soon as possible .

Comment: you will need server side script for this, so which are you using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17414972/get-ip-address-with-javascript

Comment: Google first before posting a question

Answer (score 1):

What language are you using (server-side)?

If you want to do this in PHP, here's how:

```
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
?>


<form>
<!-- other form elements here -->
<input type="text" name="ip" value="<?php if isset($ip) { echo $ip; } ?>" />
</form>
```

The first part gets the users IP address. The second part prints its value in the text field.

Answer (score 0):

You want your users to see their ip address in a text box?

Assuming you have to do it on the client-side, you need to use javacript.  Like this (taken from [How to get client's IP address using javascript only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/get-client-ip-using-just-javascript)):

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    function getip(json){
      alert(json.ip); // alerts the ip address
      // instead of the alert, assign the value to your text box
    }
</script>

<script type="application/javascript" src="http://jsonip.appspot.com/?callback=getip"></script>
```