# Constructing the script source dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the below code for retrieving the host ip address:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://l2.io/ip.js"></script>
```

I need to retrieve the ip address from the above url and construct another URL something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://<above_ip_address>:8080/MonarchDemo/.."></script>
```

Both the scripts are present inside the `<body>` tag of the html file like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://l2.io/ip.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://<ip_address>:8080/MonarchDemo/.."></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Running this html file, the first `script` is displaying the correct IP address but I am not able to replace that IP address in the second `script`. Please guide.

Comment: is first script dynamic?? how are you getting ipaddres

Comment: No, its not. The first script is a static one. The second script is dynamic based on the IP address returned by the first script

Comment: do you have some ipaddress in some js variable

Comment: No I dont have. I need to retrive it fromt eh first script, save it in a variable and then use it in the second script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question exactly, but instead of trying to replace a static script tag, why not dynamically create one?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://l2.io/ip.js?var=ipAddressFound"></script>

var scr = document.createElement("script");

scr.type = "text/javascript";
scr.src = 'http://' + ipAddressFound + ':8080/MonarchDemo/..'; // Use the IP found above
scr.innerHTML = null;
document.body.appendChild(scr);
```

Credit to this answer for the var creation through script:
[Get client IP address via third party web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17414972/get-ip-address-with-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for the guide.  agree with this. But the first script is returning me the ip address, how to replace that in the above code you posted?

Comment: @user182944 In the above code there is a variable `ipAddressFound` - That would hold the value returned by the first script. Sorry if I'm missing something.

Comment: but how will the save the ip address retrieved by the script `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://l2.io/ip.js"></script>` in the variavle which you named as `ipAddressFound`?

Comment: Is not it possible to save it in a variable using the first script ?

Comment: @user182944 Notice the "var=" at the end of the script now?

Comment: Ok so what I can understand is: the query string passed here `var=ipAddressFound` in the `src` of the `script` is stored in a variable and the same variable is used later on for dynamically retrieving the IP address right?

Comment: @user182944 Almost. The script determines the IP address of the user, that IP address is then stored in a variable called `ipAddressFound`, and at this point you can do what you want with the IP (in this case use it to load another script).

Answer (score 1):

You can use **jQuery** to load your script [take a look here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)

```
$.getScript('http://<ip_address>:8080/MonarchDemo/..', function(){});
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to load it within an ajax call following the execution of your first script?

check out http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

try something like:

```
var getIP = function () {
    var ipadress;
    // code for IP-Adress retrieval here
    return ipadress;
}

// setup the URL
var url = getIP() + ":8080/MonarchDemo/..."
$.getScript( url, function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
    // do want you want to do
    // i.e.
    // console.log( data ); // Data returned
    // console.log( textStatus ); // Success
    // console.log( jqxhr.status ); // 200
    // console.log( "Load was performed." );
});
```

As an alternative you could just instert the second script block with javascript (document.write ...) on runtime.

Answer (score 1):

you will have to dynamically generate the second script tag ..

```
   var dynamicScript = document.createElement('script');
   var scriptUrl = ":8080/MonarchDemo/..";

   var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");

   //fetch the source and parse out the domain ..

   var domain = scripts[0].getAttribute('src').replace('http://', '').replace('https://', '').split(/[/?#]/)[0];

   dynamicScript.setAttribute('src', "//" + domain + scriptUrl);

   document.body.appendChild(dynamicScript)
```