# How to get ip address of remote client

Tags: node.js, ip, jasperserver

I've hosted a jasper server,

```
http://example.com/jasperserver/......
```

and I get the required PDF by hitting the URL above. At the jasperserver's front, I want to get the IP address of the client which requests the PDF, so I can print it in the PDF and also use data-source hosted on the client's address.

Is there a way I can pull this out from the headers or any other method jasperserver provides?

Comment: which language you are using on server side?

Comment: I'm using js, but how does it matter? I'm using ireports to create the reports

Comment: You can use DNS Lookup.

Comment: [Get ip address via JS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17414995/3423104) OR [some other APIs](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19953367/3423104)

Comment: You can get Ip with any method on your backend and attach it to your report as parameter (in report request)