# jQuery $.get not working (Not Found 404)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get, ip

Please help me with a problem - `get` function not working for http://wtfismyip.com/text or http://www.passwordrandom.com/query?command=ip

Code:

```
<span id="global_ip" class="global_ip">global ip - get test</span>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#global_ip').click(function () {  
    alert('click!');      
    $.get({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://www.passwordrandom.com/query?command=ip",
        dataType: "text"
    }).done(function (res) {
        alert(res);
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Call failed: " + textStatus + ", " + errorThrown);
    });
});
```

Comment: you can do something like this http://jsbin.com/negatu/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this, it's a violation of same origin policy.

> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy); the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, port, or protocol.

But this could help you achieve what you want: [Get ip address with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17414972/get-ip-address-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <span id="global_ip" class="global_ip">global ip - get test</span>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                $('#global_ip').click(function()
                {
                        $.get("http://www.passwordrandom.com/query?command=ip", function(data)
                        {
                                alert(data);
                        });
                });
</script>
```

Comment: Is your API under same domain ?
What error you are getting ?