# $.getJSON will not run function after data is returned

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble getting the users IP to persist to the next function because every time I call `$.getJSON` it skips my function. I am certain that the JSON being returned is fine because when I run the code shown here:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
$.getJSON("http://www.telize.com/jsonip?callback=?",
    function(json) {
        document.write("My IP address is : ", json.ip);
    }
);
</script>
```

the IP is written to the screen exactly as you would expect. Here is my most recent attempt:

```
<script type="application/javascript">

function verifyRecaptchaAnswer() {
  var privateKey = 'privateKey'; 
  var challengeValue = $('#recaptcha_challenge_field').val();
  var responseValue = "manual_challenge" ;
  var userIP = $('#hiddenField').val();
  $.post("http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/verify",
    { privatekey: privateKey, remoteip: userIP, challenge: challengeValue, response: responseValue },
    function(data) {
      return data;
    }
  ); 
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  var hiddenField = document.createElement('input');
  hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "ipHolder")
  hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
  hiddenField.setAttribute("id", "hiddenField");

  $.getJSON("http://www.telize.com/jsonip?callback=?",
    function(json) {
      hiddenField.setAttribute("value", json.ip);
    }
  );

  $('#submit').on("click", function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    verifyRecaptchaAnswer();
  });
});
</script>
```

I have tried everything under the sun in that `function(json){}` block, but none of it works. Except of course for the example shown on the website, http://www.telize.com/ , which is the first code block posted. I found this site after finding this stack post: [How to get client IP address using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641868/how-to-get-client-ip-address-using-jquery), which looks like the same thing. I haven't even gotten to testing the `verifyRecaptchaAnswer` function yet, but that is what I want the user IP for.

Comment: Functions like `$.getJSON` and `$.post` are **asynchronous**.  The callback function isn't run until the HTTP request completes.

Comment: `return data;` is pretty useless there. Apart from that, what exactly is the problem? You are saying `document.write("My IP address is : ", json.ip);` works, but `hiddenField.setAttribute("value", json.ip);` doesn't?

Comment: @FelixKling the code implicitly expects that the "hidden field" will have had its value populated by the time the "verify" function runs.

Comment: @Pointy: I know, but that function is not run until the button is clicked. Most likely this is the problem, but I just want a proper explanation of the problem from the OP.

Comment: @FelixKling Oh I see; yes of course.

Comment: @FelixKling, yes document.write(...); works, and anything else I put in the function does not.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing this line:

```
document.body.appendChild(hiddenField);
```

Comment: PS - might wanna pass `event` through the `submit` click function: `.on('click', function(event) { ... });`