# get Harware address or get unique id from device

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, get, controller, mac-address

I have found the following to my mvc controller. But how will I get the result in my cshtml? anyone have an idea?

```
  private string GetMacAddress()
        {
        string macAddresses = string.Empty;

        foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
            {
            if (nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
                {
                macAddresses += nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
                break;
                }
            }

        return macAddresses;
        }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641868/how-to-get-client-ip-address-using-jquery

Comment: Thanks for this Matt.. I use this solution: @Request.UserHostAddress to get the ip address.. i am looking for the unique (hardware) address

Comment: ah sorry about that,  here is the link regarding the mac address http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385/mac-addresses-in-javascript

Answer (score -1):

Since it is a string you can send it with a ViewBag 
http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/viewbag-in-asp.net-mvc

in your conroller you can write something like this

```
ViewBag.macAdress = GetMacAddress();
```

and at the cshtml end you can write something like

```
<p>@ViewBag.macAdress<p>
```