# How to get Mac address of computer that access my website?

Tags: jquery, python, flask

I have a website so how to get mac address of computer that access my website?

Please help me answer with code python, flask or jquery.

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible directly. You need to use OS programs to determine the mac address.

But of course you can get the IP-Address of a remote user using jQuery:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641868/how-to-get-client-ip-address-using-jquery
Btw what do you need the MAC-Address for? Maybe there's a simpler solution to your problem.

Comment: I want to check allow client mac address to access my website.

Answer (score 1):

No, getting the clients MAC Address via JS is impossible, heres why:
[MAC addresses in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385/mac-addresses-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

in general you can only access the MAC address of a machine on your LAN - if the computer you are talking about is outside of this then you probably can't

here's some python code:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen('arp %s' % ip_address, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print p.stdout
```