# current IP address of client in AJAX and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is in my php page

```
// Change the line below to your timezone!
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
$date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){
  $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];}
elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
  $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];}
else{
  $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];}
//print json_encode(array('ip' => $ip));

//echo $date;

echo json_encode(array(
    'date' => $date,
    'ip' => $ip
));
```

This is in my ajax

```
var currentservertime = "";
var clientip = "";
$.ajax({
    url: '../currenttime.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        currentservertime = data.date;
        clientip = data.ip;

    },
    error: function(data) {
        var message = "Error Occured!";
        $("#dialog").html(message);
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            title: dialogtitle
        });
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    }
});
```

Then I have `console.log(clientip)` in a button click it out puts

`::1`

In console. Why is this the IP that I am getting in PHP page.

The sample I followed is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641868/how-to-get-client-ip-address-using-jquery)

Comment: Because you are using localhost that means http://localhost/sitename.

Comment: @d.coder i see if i access my local host from other PC it will show me the IP of that PC?

Comment: Yes it will show you the IP of other PC.

Comment: @d.coder i think you deserve the credit will you answer the question so i can accept your answer by the way is there no way to make it show my PC address ? just a though..

Comment: When would you like to see your system IP? Accessing site from your system's browser or other PC browser? BTW, i have added answer for you to accept/upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using localhost that means https://localhost/sitename.

But if you access your localhost from other PC by your system IP then it will show you the IP of other PC

Answer (score 0):

You get `::1` cause you're using localhost host as explained here :

[IP Address of the machine in PHP gives ::1 but why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10517371/ip-address-of-the-machine-in-php-gives-1-but-why)

Answer (score 0):

From localhost you will get your ip address only that is ::1
For get your internet ip address from your local machine then you have to make change in your PHP script, IF ip not found or not valid then you have to use third party API.

```
// Change the line below to your timezone!
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
$date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){
    $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
}
elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
    $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}
else{
    $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}

if(empty($ip) || $ip=="::1" || $ip=="127.0.0.1")
{
    $ip = file_get_contents('http://api.ipify.org');
}
//print json_encode(array('ip' => $ip));

//echo $date;

echo json_encode(array(
'date' => $date,
'ip' => $ip
));
```